# Iterate over a pandas column that has list values and store those in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as shown:

```
    text
0   [is, upset, that, he, cant, update, his, faceb...
1   [dived, many, time, for, the, ball, managed, t...
2   [my, whole, body, feel, itchy, and, like, it, ...
3   [no, it, not, behaving, at, all, im, mad, why,...
4   [not, the, whole, crew]
```

I would like to have the dataframe text column have only the values of the

```
    text
0   is upset that he cant update his faceb...
1   dived many time for the ball managed t...
2   my whole body feel itchy and like it ...
3   no it not behaving at all im mad why...
4   not the whole crew
```

I have tried the following but seems not to work:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Wondering what might I be missing?

Comment: `df['text'] = df['text'].str.join(' ')`?

Comment: should be  `.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in x]))`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way turn lists into rows is use `explode()` [Dataframe explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
df = df.explode(text)
```

Comment: here explode will not help, OP wants to join the values inside array.

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehension`:

```
df['text'] = [' '.join(map(str, li)) for li in df['text']]
```

Comment: This gives an error: "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"

Comment: Do you any nan?

Comment: Nope. Let me try this: ".apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in x]))" as you've mentioned.